# Ubuntu not seeing Windows 7 in bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, bootloader

While I was installing Ubuntu I unplugged my Windows 7 HDD so I wouldn't accidentally partition it.  I installed Ubuntu, shut off my computer, plugged back the HDD, rebooted (and using the BIOS boot menu, selected Ubuntu). Ubuntu recognized the HDD with Windows 7 on it, and can mount it fine. However, I cannot get it added to the boot-loader.

I have tried boot-repair with several different settings, and it detects Windows 7, but it doesn't add it to the boot-loader.

Here are two of the boot repair logs
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7158644/
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7164637/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try install grub.
Browse for boot-repair.

[help link](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/boot-repair-fix-ubuntu-boot-issues.html)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I have tried a full reinstall of grub (removal AND install of it), both through boot repair's purge and reinstall grub option and by myself